# Event listener when cq-FileUpload-clear is clicked

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have javascript function that listens to any change in value made to coral-FileUpload element on the cq dialog.

```
$('coral-FileUpload').on('change', (event) => {
            // my code
});
```

The above code works fine when any asset is dropped from DAM. However, it does not detect any change when the 'clear' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation over at https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.FileUpload.html#Coral.FileUpload:events it looks like you need to bind your javascript to another event

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
$(".cq-FileUpload-clear").on('click', (event) => {
       //your code 
});
```